# PDFBOX PDF->Text encoding working on a computer and not on the other one

Tags: java, encoding, pdfbox

I am extracting text from a swedish pdf and the swedish characters on my computer are displayed as a ?

However when testing the same code on another machine it is working and parsing well.

I suspect this has to do with some windows configuration of the encoding (or jvm?).

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Can you provide a code example? Are you using a specified locale or are you using the standard configuration?

Comment: standard configuration i read a swedish pdf file and ends up with weird encoded characters such as "Ã¥" . If i change the JVM encoding to -Dfile.encoding="ISO-8859-1" it works and output the rights characters. However i will not only have swedish files... I supose my file is encoded in ISO-8859-1 but most my other files will be in UTF-8. Is there a workaround in order to manage all the # encodings

Comment: what method are you using to extract text? which version of pdfbox are you using?